# How can I call SQLite row data reversely?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to show a row data in SQLite reversly in textview, for example if my row is: 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
I want to show:
"E", "D", "C", "B", "A"

Here is my Code:

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mydataBase", null);
int rows = c.getCount();
int cols = c.getColumnCount();

    c.moveToFirst();

    // outer for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TextView myTableRowTextView = new TextView(this);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        // inner for loop
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            myTableRowTextView = new TextView(this);
            myTableRowTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            myTableRowTextView.setTextSize(18);

            Cursor cc = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myDataBase", null); 
            myTableRowTextView.setText(c.getString(j));
            row.addView(myTableRowTextView);
        }
        c.moveToNext();
        myTableLayout.addView(row);
    }
```

The Problem is in line: myTableRowTextView.setText(c.getString(j));
where displays my row in textView, Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You could always request the specific fields instead of the * of course if the table has more columns added you will have to change this code or risk not grabbing that info.

Comment: Additionally you could change your loop to count down from (cols-1) to 0  ie (int j = (cols - 1); j > -1; j--)  Not sure if it would be j > -1 or j > 0 I would test if I were you.

Comment: Nothing could be easier: just append this to your query: `... ORDER BY SortedField DESC` (the default is `ASC` and can be omitted). Obviously enough, `ASC` is "Ascending" and `DESC` is "Descending". By the way, instead of querying your table n times, get all the results once and then move though the records which are stored in your cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all columns in other way with something like this

```
for (int j = cols -1; j > -1; j--) {
            myTableRowTextView = new TextView(this);
            myTableRowTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            myTableRowTextView.setTextSize(18);

            Cursor cc = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myDataBase", null); 
            myTableRowTextView.setText(c.getString(j));
            row.addView(myTableRowTextView);
        }
```